# Keyword search using match against, get exclusive results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a column `tags` which contains keywords for searching. I have a fulltext index on it.

I select items based on the following:

```
WHERE MATCH(tags) AGAINST (:keyword)
```

Example table of keywords/tags in the `tags` column:

```
row #1  car city
row #2  car town
```

When I search for "car", it will return both rows as expected. However when I search for "car city", it still returns the first 2 instead of just the first row.

How would I make it exclusive rather than inclusive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [boolean mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) to make the requirement explicit.  `+keyword` means it is required.

```
WHERE MATCH(tags) AGAINST ('+car +city' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```